# Java multiplying two doubles into another double

Tags: java, double

I'm trying to replace `payRate * hoursWorked` into a single variable `grossPay` but when I do it's returning a value of 0.0 for any calculation. `double grossPay` is commented out on purpose so you can see what I was trying to do.

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class elseIfPayroll{

        public static void main(String[] args){


        double hoursWorked =0.00;
        double payRate =0.00;
        int dependents =0;



        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        NumberFormat f = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");


            System.out.print("Enter pay rate: ");
            payRate = keyboard.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Enter hours worked: ");
            hoursWorked = keyboard.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Enter amount of dependents: ");
            dependents = keyboard.nextInt();

            double grossPay= (payRate * hoursWorked);

//gross pay decision statements

        if (hoursWorked<=40) {
            System.out.println("Total $ Earned: " + payRate * hoursWorked); 
            }

            else if (hoursWorked >= 40) {
                System.out.println("Total $ Earned: " + payRate * hoursWorked +(payRate * 0.5));
                }

            else if (hoursWorked>=60){
                System.out.println("Total $ Earned: " + payRate * hoursWorked + (payRate * 2));
                }






//else if statements for dependents

        if (dependents == 0){
                    f.format(payRate * hoursWorked);
            }

            else if (dependents == 1){
                    f.format(payRate * hoursWorked - (payRate *                                         hoursWorked*0.04) );
            }

            else if (dependents == 2){
                     f.format(payRate * hoursWorked - (payRate *                                                hoursWorked*0.0775));
            }

            else if (dependents == 3){
                    f.format(payRate * hoursWorked - (payRate *                                                 hoursWorked*0.1125) );
            }

            else if (dependents == 4){
                    f.format(payRate * hoursWorked - (payRate *                                                 hoursWorked*0.145) );
            }

            else if (dependents == 5){
                    f.format(payRate * hoursWorked - (payRate *                                                 hoursWorked*0.175) );
            }

            else if (dependents >= 6){
                    f.format(payRate * hoursWorked - (payRate *                                                 hoursWorked*0.2025) );
            }


            System.out.println("New gross Pay: " + f.format(payRate * hoursWorked - (payRate *                                      hoursWorked*0.04)));




    }
}
```

Comment: If youre multiplying and it turns out to 0, one of the factors is 0 because there are no zero divisors in the reals.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Both multiplication operands are zero at the point of the commented out multiplication, so of course it is going to get a zero result. I think it may be time for an [sscce](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Did you already debugged your program? If not, please do it and find your problem.

Comment: I'm really new to java an I have no idea how to debug.. I just want to know how to put payRate and hoursWorked into one variable .. grossPay

Answer (score 7):

In Java - and many other languages - doing

```
result = operand1 operator operand2
```

calculates the result *immediately*. Java doesn't keep in memory the program line in *result* that would update *grossPay* as soon as *hoursWorked* or *payRate* are modified, but only the *double* result.

So when you

```
    double hoursWorked =0.00;
    double payRate =0.00;
    double grossPay= (payRate * hoursWorked);
```

*grossPay* takes the result of `0 * 0` (ie zero).

You just have to move a bit the *grossPay* calculation

```
        System.out.print("Enter pay rate: ");
        payRate = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter hours worked: ");
        hoursWorked = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter amount of dependents: ");
        dependents = keyboard.nextInt();

        double grossPay= (payRate * hoursWorked);
```

to make it to work.

Comment: @montenegroxnj: I think you should accept this answer. Also, from the change log it appears that you altered your original code in order to reflect what ring0 posted; I think you should have left the original (wrong) code unchanged instead.